# How to Show maximum rate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data which contains suicide rates in countries over the years and i want to show for each year most suicide value for age range, for example.

```
Country,Year,Age,Suicides
Albania,1987,15-24 years,21
Albania,1987,35-54 years,16
Albania,1987,15-24 years,14
Albania,1987,75+ years,1
Albania,1987,25-34 years,9
Albania,1987,75+ years,1
Albania,1987,35-54 years,6
Albania,1987,25-34 years,4
Albania,1987,55-74 years,1
Albania,1987,5-14 years,0
Albania,1987,55-74 years,0
Albania,1987,5-14 years,0
```

In Albania in the year of 1987 most suicided persons age interval is 15-24 and i want to show the most suicided values in every year, every country. How can i do that

Comment: What type is this table? is it matrix? a dict?

Comment: Are the rows with duplicate <Country>,<Year>,<age> <different suicide rate> on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO('''Country,Year,Age,Suicides
Albania,1987,15-24 years,21 
Albania,1987,35-54 years,16 
Albania,1987,15-24 years,14 
Albania,1987,75+ years,1
Albania,1987,25-34 years,9 
Albania,1987,75+ years,1 
Albania,1987,35-54 years,6 
Albania,1987,25-34 years,4 
Albania,1987,55-74 years,1 
Albania,1987,5-14 years,0 
Albania,1987,55-74 years,0 
Albania,1987,5-14 years,0''')

df = pd.read_csv(s)


df.groupby(['Country', 'Year', 'Age']).Suicides.sum().idxmax()
```

Output:
('Albania', 1987, '15-24 years')